# How do you read the console output from windows service?

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services, console-application

I have console application ThirdPartyApplications.exe, that I have to run from windows service.
Console application give me reposes: OK, NOT OK and ERROR.

I need to capture these responses in my windows service.

I created function

```
 using (var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\ThirdPartyApplications.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "3";
            p.Start();
            string o = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            p.WaitForExit();
        }
```

How can I capture this output?

EDIT

```
 using (var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\ThirdPartyBatch.bat";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "file.zip -user.properties";
            p.Start();
            string o = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            p.WaitForExit();
        }
```

Batch file is

```
@echo off
call run.bat %* 1>log\out.txt 2>log\err.txt
@echo code %ERRORLEVEL%
exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

here, in my variable o, I do not get message "code 10"

if I have

```
@ECHO off
ECHO Hello
PAUSE
```

Here, I get message "Hello", but if I change batch file

```
@ECHO off
call run.bat %* 1>log\out.txt 2>log\err.txt
ECHO Hello
PAUSE
```

I do not get message "Hello"

Any help?

Comment: What problem do you have with your code?

Comment: It start working now. But, I have now different situation. I have batch file `@echo off
call run.bat %* 1>log\out.txt 2>log\err.txt
@echo exits with code %ERRORLEVEL%
exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%` . When I start this from cmd, I get exit code, but in my windows service o is empty.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I capture this output?

Only when not running as a service.

An executable on Windows has to call specific APIs (directly as a Win32 application or indirectly under a framework like .NET), if it doesn't call these (eg. logic based on a command line switch<sup>1</sup>) then it is a normal executable.

When run as a service the executable is started by the Service Control Manager (SCM), and there is no access to standard output, error or input.

---

<sup>1</sup> This can be useful when developing and debugging services: an "interactive" mode allowing easy running from the command line or within a debugger.

Comment: what is interactive mode?

Comment: @StayCool Run with lots of console output and don't connect to service control manager to make debugging easier. Something the author of the service implements.

Comment: I got you.                                                                                                       
When I started running app via SCM it became very hard to debug even small bugs. I've solved it using exceptiong handling for like every possible error and logging to eventLog (registered EventLog source beforehand into app)